# Questions on PageRank and its implementation

Tags: c#, .net, pagerank

First, I am wondering if there is a reputable .NET library that can compute PageRank scores. I know there are many implementation in R, Python and Java. But I couldn't find one that can run on .NET. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Second, I am wondering it make sense to apply PageRank to a large sparse graph, say a lot of nodes are isolated, only a small portion have links to others. In that case, what is the PageRank score for those isolated nodes? It seems to vary by implementation but I thought it should always be (1 - d)/N where d is the damping factor and N is the total nodes.

Explanation are appreciated.